# How to print the address of a NSString in Xcode Debugger

Tags: xcode, pointers, nsstring, lldb

Usually in the lldb debugger, if you do a po on an object its address is also shown along with the description. However, in case of a NSString the address is not shown. So the question is that is there a way to see it.

PS - NSLog %p in source code is not the answer I am looking for.

Comment: There is: `po NSLog(@"%p", object);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple use "p" in place of "po".

Example:

```
NSString *string1 = @"test 1";
NSString *string2 = @"test 2";
```

(lldb) po string1
test 1
(lldb) p string1
(NSString *) $2 = 0x0000000100003af0 @"test 1"
(lldb) p string2
(NSString *) $3 = 0x0000000100003b10 @"test 2"

Comment: Thanks, works. PS - I hope it skips leading 0s with NSLog %p as this is what I got.. (lldb) p class1.variableA1
(NSString *) $0 = 0x00004a54 @"A1 initialized"
2014-01-23 20:38:56.348 UnderstandBasics[1956:70b] Address of A1 - 0x4a54

Comment: I wish we were back in the land of 16bit addresses, so much easier. :-) Of course we were writing in assembler, memory was 8KB and the debugger was a bank of 16 switches and leds, one for each bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `register read` to read the address in memory.
it will log like `eax = 0x00004940  @"string"`and with other register address and description.